# How to mimic a swipe without a mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

**In General:**
I need my nav to behave like a mobile app (swipe effect), but WITHOUT accessing it via a mobile product. (So JQuery Mobile and such isn't applicable here... at least I don't think.)

**Specifics:**
My nav (example attached below) is a set of horizontally arranged icons. I would like to be able to scroll horizontally, but instead of simply scrolling the icons over, I'd like them to slide in increments (much like how an iPhone's pages slide into discrete positions with swipes across the screen.) This means regardless of how much the user scrolls, only the same amount of slide is performed.

[View work-in-progress here](http://www.davidraponi.com/test)

**My Problem:**
So I currently have this (crappy/buggy) version working, but it's based on JQuery's .mousemove() which means as I cause the menu to move, the cursor is still also moving and no longer over the icon I wish to click. If I based it on .scroll(), then the containing div would have to be scrollable (which would show the scrollbars).

**So: Is there...**
a) an example of this already done somewhere? or
b) a way to make a div scrollable but without showing the scrollbars

This site is being used in a specific way for a specific purpose, so please don't reply just to tell me that hidden scrollbars on a scrollable div is bad juju/annoying for the users.

I found something called "Web In Touch".  Could this help?

Many MANY thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/

Have you tried content flow? It can do horizontal scrolling for you on button presses (and you can map this to something else). I understand this isn't what you want exactly, but it might work, since you want to horizontally flow/scroll image icons.

Comment: I hadn't seen this before, it looks great. I'll run it past the chap i'm working with. Thanks!